# Using the java.time API in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying out Java 8 Date Time Api `java.time` using Scala REPL. Just encountered the problem below:

[image]

I do understand that the keyword `with` is reserved in scala, but also it is used in the API. Any idea on how to mitigate the limits?

Comment: I've managed to solve it by enclosing the with keyword using `` characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try wrapping the with with tick marks as follows:

```
val nextWed = today.`with`(java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY))
```

Adding the ticks designates it a literal identifier.